# nodejs program i am unable to get output ,where i write logic wrong?

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3001;
let server = http.createServer((request,response) => {
        response.statusCode=200;
        response.setHeader('content-Type','text/html');
        if(url==='/index') {
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'), 'utf8', (err,data) => {
                if(err) throw err; response.end(data)
            });
        } else if(url==='/contact') {
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'contact.html'), 'utf8', (err,data)=> {
                if(err)throw err;response.end(data)
            });
        }

    else if (url==='/about') {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'about.html'),'utf8',(err,data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            response.end(data);
        })
    }
    else if (url==='/profile') {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'profile.html'),'utf8', (err,data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            response.end(data)
        })
    }

    else if (url==='/service') {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'service.html'), 'utf8', (err,data) => {
            if(err)throw err;
            response.end(data)
        })
    }
});

server.listen(port,hostname, ()=> {
    console.log(`serevr is started at http://${hostname}:${port}`)
});
```

**http:this url loading continuously but no webpage display on browser**

Comment: Can you please share the `package.json` file. Also, what is your current output and what should be the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `url` module. To access the current route, you could use `request.url` and there is no `setHeader` method on the `request` object

Here is a working example

```js
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3001;
let server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  if (request.url === "/index" || request.url === "/") {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      response.end(data);
    });
  } else if (request.url === "/contact") {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "contact.html"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      response.end(data);
      response.end(data);
    });
  } else if (request.url === "/about") {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "about.html"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      response.end(data);
      response.end(data);
    });
  } else if (request.url === "/profile") {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "profile.html"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      response.end(data);
      response.end(data);
    });
  } else if (request.url === "/service") {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "service.html"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      response.end(data);
      response.end(data);
    });
  }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`server is started at http://${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```